# How get query for array of objects in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to form a query in such a way to get only **status : active** list. It should list only the active status. need to filter it down .

```
"users" : {
                "assigned" : [
                        {
                                "userId" : ObjectId("5d9fd84b3d598088d2ea5e0b"),
                                "firstName" : "ramasamy",
                                "userImage" : "69_20160719103303_user.png",
                                "status" : "inactive",
                                "assignedDate" : ISODate("2017-05-25T05:18:37Z")
                        },
                        {
                                "userId" : ObjectId("5d9fd8233d598088d2ea5dd1"),
                                "firstName" : "karthik",
                                "userImage" : "karthik_1589782232510.jpeg",
                                "status" : "active",
                                "assignedDate" : null
                        }],
                        "incharge" : [{
                                "userId" : ObjectId("5d9fd81f3d598088d2ea5dcc"),
                                "firstName" : "sathish",
                                 "status" : "inactive",
                                "assignedDate" : ISODate("2017-04-12T16:43:24Z")
                        },
                        { "userId" : ObjectId("5d9fd8203d598088d2ea5dcd"),
                                "firstName" : "santhana vadivelan",
                                "status" : "active",
                                "assignedDate" : ISODate("2017-05-09T18:20:25Z")
                        }]
                }
```

I tried using find query,but noting worked out.

I need the result to be like.

```
"users" : {
                "assigned" : [
                        {
                                "userId" : ObjectId("5d9fd8233d598088d2ea5dd1"),
                                "firstName" : "karthik",
                                "userImage" : "karthik_1589782232510.jpeg",
                                "status" : "active",
                                "assignedDate" : null
                        }]
                        "incharge" : [{ "userId" : ObjectId("5d9fd8203d598088d2ea5dcd"),
                                "firstName" : "santhana vadivelan",
                                "status" : "active",
                                "assignedDate" : ISODate("2017-05-09T18:20:25Z")
                        }]
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the $ keyword.
This will allow you to perform queries on all the elements in an inner array.

For example: `db.collection.find({'users.assigned.$.status': 'active'})`